# Move files with python3

Tags: python-3.x, move

So I just found out that python modules `os`, `shutil` are no longer available to clone from: https://pypi.python.org/

and after some research I did not find any replacement..

So the question is: how to move files from `dir/fileX` -> `/dir2/fileX`

AND / OR is there possibility to rename the folder if needed to 'move' all the files in it?

Using Linux / macOS

Thank you.

---

Tl;dr OS and SHUTIL are part of standard library in python 3x

Comment: [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) and [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) are part of the standard library, no need to get anything from pypi

Answer (score 0):

shutil is the default library in python versions. So you can use shutil.move(src, dest) to recursively move folder from one repository to another.